# Java File runs with java FileName.java command but doesn't compile with javac Filename.java

Tags: java

**File name:** B.java

```
public class B
{
    public static void main(String[] args){}
}
public class A{}
```

- `java B.java` runs without error
- `javac B.java` gives a compile error: `class A needs to be declared in a file A.java`

I understand that a java file can not have more than one public class, but why can a java file run without error using the `java` command when you get compile errors for the code using `javac`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Java-11+ allows launching Single-File Source-Code programs](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330) without compiling. You can learn more about it from [this article](https://www.infoq.com/articles/single-file-execution-java11/). As per the specification, if the first class in the file has `main`, it executes the same without caring for other `public` classes in the file. Thus, if you change the order of classes in the file and try `java B.java`, it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

My guess, and it is only a guess since I haven't used Java 11 extensively, is that:

- The "javac" command produces class files that can be combined into a large program, and thus there could be multiple references to class A "elsewhere" in the program.  It is this generality that produces the restriction on one public class per source file (though frankly I don't see why compiling B.java cannot result in A.class and B.class)
- The "java" command processes a single source file. From that point of view it is irrelevant whether A is public or not; A can be used from within the single file (same package!) in any case.